# Issue trying to create a replica set

Tags: bash, mongodb, macos, database-replication

I am currently having issues with setting up a replica set (as per the instructions on a mongoDB tutorial on creating a replica set) on my Mac (Sierra). I have downloaded the associated .sh file and when I run this code:

`bash < create_replica_set__m101p_52b35df6e2d423678d3b9d48.19830756d7a7.sh`

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017 --oplogSize 64 --fork --smallfiles
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "2.log" --dbpath /data/rs2 --port 27018 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "3.log" --dbpath /data/rs3 --port 27019 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
```

I get this error in my terminal:

`mkdir: /data/rs1: Permission denied
mkdir: /data/rs2: Permission denied
mkdir: /data/rs3: Permission denied
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 27998
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28001
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28004
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100`

I have attempted to do this with sudo and I get the same result.

I have attempted to run this both in my downloads folder and on my desktop. I have moved it into my home directory, and I get nothing logged out to the console, it just returns a new line.

What do I need to do here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo mkdir /data
sudo chmod -R 755 /data && sudo chown -R `whoami` /data
# now run the script
```

It may not be necessary to run the first command, if /data exists already just run the second command.

The error codes are because MongoDB can't create the database files necessary because the directories don't exist.